# Is the split normal distribution analytic on $\mathbb{C}$?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis

I wonder if the split normal distribution which expressed as following is analytic on $\mathbb{C}$ or not?

$  p(x)= \left\{ 
\begin{array}{l l}
  \frac{2}{1+\gamma} \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \exp{\left(-\frac{x^2}{2} \right)} & \quad \text{if}~ x \le 0\\
\frac{2\gamma}{1+\gamma}\cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi\gamma^2}} \exp{\left(-\frac{x^2}{2\gamma^2} \right)} & \quad \text{otherwise}
\end{array} \right.$

where $\gamma$ is a constant greater than 1. 
In fact, I'm not too sure how to extend this to the complex plane and I checked Cauchy-Riemann equations and it seems to hold for the split normal distribution. Any suggestions? Thanks for your time in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until you decide how to extend the function to the complex plane, it is meaningless to ask if the CR equations hold (since they apply to a function of a complex variable).

The natural extension is to replace $e^{\frac{x^2}{2}}$ and $e^{\frac{x^2}{2\gamma}}$ by $e^{\frac{z^2}{2}}$ and $e^{\frac{z^2}{2\gamma}}$ respectively, and say that the first form is used when $\Re(z) \geq 0$ and the second form when $\Re(z) < 0$.  But that function is not even complex differentiable on points on the imaginary axis other than the origin.

Of course, that does not prove there is no analytic function $q(z)$ that matches $p(\Re(z))$ on the real line, and even if it did, that does not prove you can't find some condition other than $\Re(z) \geq 0$ that splits the Gaussians and results in an analytic funtion after all.  But I would be surprised if such exists, except in the trivial case of one form if $|z| = 0$ and the other form if $|z| > 0$ .

Comment: Hi Mark, you are totally right about this, Thanks for your time and answer.